Expand dashboard widget button and Subscribe button missing on Salesforce dashboard
We have created a static dashboard where the running user is System Admin. The dashboard folder has been shared with a public group with manage access.
When we view this dashboard as a System Admin, it shows the Expand dashboard widget buttons & Subscribe button. But when we view it as a user from the shared public group, then these buttons disappear.
We have provided the following permissions to the viewing user through a permission set:

Create and Customize Dashboards
Edit My Dashboards
Create Dashboard Folders
Edit My Reports
Schedule Reports
Subscribe to Reports: Add Recipients
Subscribe to Reports
Subscribe to Dashboards
Export Reports
Subscribe to Reports: Set Running User
Subscribe to Reports: Send to Groups and Roles
Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients
Create and Customize Reports
Create Report Folders
Run Reports
Report Builder (Lightning Experience)

Kindly guide us regarding this issue.
Should we raise a Salesforce support ticket regarding this issue?

This issue got resolved with Salesforce Winter '25 release. It appears that it was an issue in the previous release.
